# AudioKit Apple Sequencer Invalid beat range or track is empty

Tags: audiokit

I've added the AudioKit SDK to a very simple project and am attempting to create a very basic sequence that follows almost exactly this file in the AudioKit Cookbook project: https://github.com/AudioKit/Cookbook/blob/main/Cookbook/CookbookCommon/Sources/CookbookCommon/Recipes/MiniApps/DrumSequencer.swift

I've copied over the midi and audio files used in the sample above into my Xcode project and ensured that the URLs to those files are correct in my code, but whenever I run the app I am getting the following error in Xcode. I have tried so many different things to get this to work and nothing is working. I have traced the cause of this directly to when the AppleSequencer() is initialized.

The error in Xcode is this:

```
2023-06-11 20:13:22.124246-0600 NoteFlow[4788:2349120] [midi] MIDI.swift:init():52:Initializing MIDI (MIDI.swift:init():52)
2023-06-11 20:13:22.694782-0600 NoteFlow[4788:2349120] [seq]         SequenceTrack.cpp:977   Clear: Invalid beat range or track is empty
```

Below is my code.

```
import AudioKit
import AudioKitEX
import AVFoundation

class DrumSequencerConductor: ObservableObject, HasAudioEngine {
    let engine = AudioEngine()
    let drums = MIDISampler(name: nil)
    var sequencer: AppleSequencer = AppleSequencer(fromURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "4tracks", withExtension: "mid")!)
    
    init() {
        engine.output = drums
        
        do {
            let clapURL: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "clap_D#1", withExtension: "wav", subdirectory: "Samples")!
            let clapFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: clapURL)
            
            let snareURL: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "snare_D1", withExtension: "wav", subdirectory: "Samples")!
            let snareFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: snareURL)
            
            let hihatURL: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "closed_hi_hat_F#1", withExtension: "wav", subdirectory: "Samples")!
            let hihatFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: hihatURL)
            
            try drums.loadAudioFiles([
                clapFile,
                snareFile,
                hihatFile
            ])
        } catch {
            print("error while finding audio files \(error)")
        }
//        sequencer.clearRange(start: Duration(beats: 0), duration: Duration(beats: 100))
//        sequencer.debug()
//        sequencer.setGlobalMIDIOutput(drums.midiIn)
//        sequencer.enableLooping(Duration(beats: 4))
//        sequencer.setTempo(150)
        
//        sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 100, position: Duration(beats: 0), duration: Duration(beats: 1))
//        sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 100, position: Duration(beats: 1), duration: Duration(beats: 1))
//        sequencer.tracks[3].add(noteNumber: 30, velocity: 127, position: Duration(beats: 2.5), duration: Duration(beats: 0.5))
//        for i in 0...40 {
//            sequencer.tracks[0].add(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber(i), velocity: 100, position: Duration(beats: 0), duration: Duration(beats: 1))
//        }
        
    }
}
```

I've commented out the sequencer code just to reduce possibilities and the error is still showing as soon as this class is instantiated.

Also, just wanted to clarify that I have enabled the background audio mode.